# How to define a parameter that accepts an array of arbitrary objects in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

Within my OpenAPI spec is it possible to define a parameter as an object without having to define its properties (an anonymous object)? More specifically, I want my API to be able to accept an array of these anonymous objects.

Here's what I have, but I'm getting an "invalid parameter definition" error in the Swagger Editor.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Test API
  description: Test
  version: "1.0.0"
host: api.example.com
schemes:
  - https
basePath: /v1
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /api/example:
    post:
      description: Endpoint description
      parameters:
        - name: param1
          in: query
          description: param1
          required: true
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
        - name: param2
          in: query
          description: param2
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: error response
          schema:
            type: object
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
definitions:
  Error:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      message:
        type: string
      fields:
        type: string
```

Here's the error:

```
Object
code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
params: Array [0]
message:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
path: Array [5]
schemaId:  "http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#"
inner: Array [2]
0: Object
code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
params: Array [0]
message:  "Data does not match any schemas from 'oneOf'"
path: Array [5]
inner: Array [2]
1: Object
code:  "OBJECT_MISSING_REQUIRED_PROPERTY"
params: Array [1]
0:  "$ref"
message:  "Missing required property: $ref"
path: Array [5]
0:  "paths"
1:  "/api/example"
2:  "post"
3:  "parameters"
4:  "0"
level: 900
type:  "Swagger Error"
description:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
lineNumber: 23
```

Comment: Your definition specifies that the objects go in the query string - is this intended or are the objects supposed to go in the POST request body?

Comment: That was the problem. I changed the in value to body and that took care of it. This is the result of copy and paste and my lack of knowledge with hand editing OpenAPI. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as Helen pointed out was that I was specifying parameters as query parameters instead of a request body. Here is what I was going for:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Test API
  description: Test
  version: "1.0.0"
host: api.example.com
schemes:
  - https
basePath: /v1
consumes: 
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /api/example:
    post:
      description: Endpoint description
      parameters:
        - name: MyRequest
          in: body
          description: My parameters
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MyRequest"
      responses:
        200:
          description: error response
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
definitions:
  MyRequest:
    type: object
    properties:
      param1:
        type: array
        items:
          type: object
      param2:
        type: string
  Error:
    type: object
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int32
      message:
        type: string
      fields:
        type: string
```